# Using Key Event to return back in my application

Tags: lua, key, coronasdk

I tried this code, but I don't know where to "put it" : Is it inside the main.lua or in each level01, level02, ect... ?

I tried to insert this code, but it works only a time. I put this code before my

> scene:createScene()

```
function onBackButtonPressedAtMap(e)
    if (e.phase == "down" and e.keyName == "back") then
        --Here the key was pressed      
        downPress = true
        return true
    else 
        if (e.phase == "up" and e.keyName == "back" and downPress) then
            storyboard.returnTo = "start"
            Runtime:removeEventListener( "key", onBackButtonPressedAtMap)
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end
Runtime:removeEventListener( "key", onBackButtonPressedAtMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Realistically the key event code should be in main.lua and only setup once. There are too many issues with trying to turn it on and off in scenes.

Rob

Comment: You could put in some print statements and look at your console log and make sure it's firing.  Shouldn't this be: Runtime:addEventListener( "key", onBackButtonPressedAtMap) instead of "removeEventListener"